# How can I implement "redirect to history/previous dynamic route after successful login" using Nextauth

Tags: next.js, next.js13, next-auth

I am trying to implement a system where user will redirected to previous protected dynamic route after successful login. Let me explain briefly. First I provide you the folder structure, Login component and Nextauth settings

Using

```
"next-auth": "^4.22.3",
"next": "13.4.5",
```

Here is the folder structure for better understanding

```
src
 ┣ app
 ┃ ┣ (auth)
 ┃ ┃ ┣ login
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ page.tsx
 ┃ ┃ ┣ register
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ page.tsx 
 ┃ ┣ (private_route)
 ┃ ┃ ┣ animated-card
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ [id]
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ page.jsx
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ readme.md
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ readme2.md
 ┃ ┃ ┣ image-editor
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ [id]
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ page.jsx
 ┃ ┃ ┣ let-us-design-for-you
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ [id]
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ page.jsx
 ┃ ┣ api
 ┃ ┃ ┣ auth
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ users
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ route.js
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ [...nextauth]
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ route.js
```

**api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.js**

```
import startDb from "@/lib/db";
import UserModel from "../../../../models/userModel";
import NextAuth, { NextAuthOptions } from "next-auth";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";
import FacebookProvider from "next-auth/providers/facebook";

export const authOptions = {
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
  },
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    }),
    FacebookProvider({
      clientId: process.env.FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET,
    }),
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: "Credentials",
      credentials: {},
      async authorize(credentials, req) {
        const { email, password } = credentials;

        await startDb();

        const user = await UserModel.findOne({ email });

        if (!user) throw new Error("email/password mismatch!");

        const passwordMatch = await user.comparePassword(password);
        if (!passwordMatch) throw new Error("email/password mismatch");

        return {
          id: user._id.toString(),
          email: user.email,
          name: user.name,
          role: user.role,
        };
      },
    }),
  ],
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
  pages: {
    signIn: "/login",
    signOut: "/login",
    error: "/login",
  },
  callbacks: {
    async session({ session, token }) {
      if (session.user) {
        session.user.id = token.id;
        session.user.role = token.role;
      }

      return session;
    },

    jwt(params) {
      if (params.user?.role) {
        params.token.role = params.user.role;
        params.token.id = params.user.id;
      }
      return params.token;
    },
  },
};

const authHandler = NextAuth(authOptions);

module.exports = {
  GET: authHandler,
  POST: authHandler,
};
```

and Finally the Login Component

```
"use client";

import Image from "next/image";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Link from "next/link";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";

const Login = () => {
  const router = useRouter();

  const [showToast, setShowToast] = useState(false);
  const [type, setType] = useState("");
  const [busy, setBusy] = useState(false);
  const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState({
    email: "",
    password: "",
  });
  const [error, setError] = useState("");
  const { password, email } = userInfo;

  const handleChange = ({ target }) => {
    const { name, value } = target;
    setUserInfo({ ...userInfo, [name]: value });
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    // console.log(userInfo);

    const res = await signIn("credentials", {
      email,
      password,
      redirect: false,
    });

    if (res?.error) {
      setType("error");
      setError("Login Failed.");
      setShowToast(true);
      return;
    }
    // If login is successful
    setType("success");
    setError("Login Success.");
    setShowToast(true);
    router.push("/");
  };

  const handleToastClose = () => {
    setShowToast(false);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div className="form-control  join-item text-base">
          <div className="mb-2">
            <label className="label">
              <span className="text-base">Username or Email *</span>
            </label>
            <input
              type="text"
              onChange={handleChange}
              value={email}
              name="email"
              placeholder="example@email.com"
              className="input input-bordered w-full h-11 placeholder:italic placeholder:font-normal"
            />
          </div>
          <div>
            <label className="label">
              <span className="text-base">Password *</span>
            </label>
            <input
              type="password"
              value={password}
              name="password"
              onChange={handleChange}
              placeholder="Password at least 6 Characters long"
              className="input input-bordered w-full h-11 placeholder:italic placeholder:font-normal"
            />
          </div>
          <button className="btn btn-primary mt-4 mb-6 text-white text-base capitalize font-medium">
            Sign In
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

When a non-user attempts to access these protected routes, they are sent to the login page. These are the protected routes

1. (private_route)/animated-card/[id]/page.jsx
2. (private_route)/image-editor/[id]/page.jsx
3. (private_route)/let-us-design-for-you/[id]/page.jsx

After successful login they will be redirected to home page. But I dont want that. I want them to redirect them to the protected page where they were last redirected.

I tried to follow the next auth documentation. But did not understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the next auth is having some bugs with their app router version. One approach is to set a callbackUrl for each pages and you have to do that on the page level instead of doing it on the layout level. I'm sharing a sample code (assuming that all your pages are server-component):

```
(private_route)/animated-card/[id]/page.jsx
import { getServerSession } from 'next-auth/next'
import { redirect } from 'next/navigation'
import { authOptions } from "../api/auth/[...nextauth]/route";

const ProtectedPage = async ({params}) => {
  const session = await getServerSession(authOptions)
  if (!session) {
    redirect(`/login?callbackUrl=/animated-card/${params.id}`)
  }
  return (
    <section className='py-24'>
      <div className='container'>
          Hello from animated card{params.id}..
      </div>
    </section>
  )
}

export default ProtectedPage
```

Here, we're passing the url of the specific page that user is trying to access as a callback url and after successful login, user will be redirected to that url.

checkout this git repo for more: https://github.com/foadtkf/next-auth-playground

Comment: Does this work on client component as well? and can I make it dynamic url  ''/login?callbackUrl=/animated-card/${params.id}'' . like it can be /animated-card/ or /somethingelse/ ?

Comment: qstn1: Absolutely. The approach for client component is pretty same. Let me share an example:

const { data: session } = useSession({
    required: true,
    onUnauthenticated() {
      redirect('/signin?callbackUrl=/protected/client')
    }
  })

rest of the code will remain the same.

qstn2: I already gave you an example for dynamic urls as you can see, the id value was dynamic. the url can be anything based on your folder structure.

Answer (score 0):

You can try by replacing this in login component with

```
router.push("/");

if(userRedirectedFromProtectedPage) {
 router.back();
}
```

userRedirectedFromProtectedPage should be a state/redux value. To prevent router.back() if user visited login page normally.

```
const AuthGuard = () => {
  if(page === ProtectedRoute and !user) {
   dispatch(UserRedirect({
    userRedirectedFromProtectedPage: true
    })
   )
   router.push('login')
  }

  if(user && userRedirectedFromProtectedPage) {
    dispatch(UserRedirect({
     userRedirectedFromProtectedPage: false
    })
    router.goBack()
  }

  return (
    <>{children}</>
  )
}
export default AuthGuard
```

Comment: Does router.back support nextjs 13 app router?

Comment: And how can I catch the userRedirectedFromProtectedPage state value in nextjs 13?

Comment: Does router.back support nextjs 13 app router? Yes. It's not deprecated or anything. And how can I catch the userRedirectedFromProtectedPage state value in nextjs 13? Depends how you implemented auth-guard. I have created on in root layout, and simply update action inside if statement. Here's my example. It doesn't use redux for now. https://github.com/ArnasDickus/UABBaltic/blob/main/src/app/%5Blng%5D/components/auth-guard/auth-guard.tsx

Comment: But it's unclear to me why you used auth guard and how it handle the userRedirectedFromProtectedPage part.

Comment: I updated my message. Hopefully it will clear everything up. I used authguard to have all redirect logic in one place.

Comment: Sounds promising! How can I implement this auth guard with my current login component. How this auth guard communicate with login part?

Comment: As from my link example. AuthGuard is in main Layout. So it will run every time you visit new page, and check if user authenticated. It will also run after you login, because of next-auth rerender. So create authGuard as use client, and put into your RootLayout.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256178/discussion-between-arnas-dickus-and-auvee).

Comment: Ok Sure. Please continue